# Spring MVCを利用したファイルアップロード時のエラーハンドリング

Tags: java, spring

Spring MVC+VelocityでWebアプリを開発をしています。

最大ファイルサイズ（現状1MB）を超えるファイルをアップロードされた場合のエラーハンドリングをどうすれば良いのか分からず困っております。

下記サイトのように共通のエラーページに遷移させることは可能です。
http://kuwalab.hatenablog.jp/entry/spring_mvc41/026

ですが、今回実現したい仕様としては
　画面Aを表示→1MBを超えるファイルをアップロード→画面Aにエラーメッセージを表示
　画面Bを表示→1MBを超えるファイルをアップロード→画面Bにエラーメッセージを表示
というように、各画面にエラーを戻したいのです。

こういったことはそもそも実現可能なのでしょうか？
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらアドバイスをお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

実現可能です。

まずExceptionHandlerで例外を処理します。このとき画面Aと画面Bでコントローラクラスを分けます。こうすることで、各コントローラで同じ例外に対して異なる処理を実行させることができます。

```
@Controller
public class SampleAController {

    // 画面Aの処理を記述する

    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException ex) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("A");
        mav.addObject("message", "message A");
        return mav;
    }
}

@Controller
public class SampleBController {

    // 画面Bの処理を記述する

    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException ex) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("B");
        mav.addObject("message", "message B");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

もしグローバルに定義する場合は`@ControllerAdvice` アノテーションをつけた例外ハンドラクラスを作成しますが、そのとき課題があります。どの画面からのアクセスなのかを判断する方法が、HTTPのリファラしかありません。HttpServletRequestオブジェクトをExceptionHandlerのメソッドの引数に追加し、`httpServletRequest.getHeader("referer");`をしてリファラのURLを取得し、そのURLをもってどの画面からのアクセスかを判断することとなります。

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Component
@Order(0)
public class SampleControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException ex,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        String referer = request.getHeader("referer");
        // 画面Aからきたかを判定する何らかの方法
        if (referer.contains("A") {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("A");
            mav.addObject("message", "message A");
            return mav;
        }
        // 画面Bからきたかを判定する何らかの方法
        if (referer.contains("B") {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("B");
            mav.addObject("message", "message B");
            return mav;
        }
        return new ModelAndView("default");
    }

}
```